# How to pass a value from a custom list adapter to the Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, interface, listadapter

I am trying to pass a value from a custom list adapter to my main activity.
Basically I have a list with check boxes. When a user selects a checkbox I want a button that I previously set up as invisible to be visible. If the user unchecks the list item I want the button to be invisible again.

My ListAdapter :

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> bool = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public ListAdapter(final Activity context)
    {
        mContext = context;

        for(int i = 0; i < ListAdapter.this.getCount(); i++)
        {
            bool.add(i, false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return AppContent.ITEMS.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return AppContent.ITEMS.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup     parent)
    {
        AppInfo holder;

        //Get the item at the current position
        final AppContent.AppInfo item = AppContent.ITEMS.get(position);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            //Create the row
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_list_row_layout, parent, false);

            holder = new AppInfo();

            //Set data to the different views
            holder.txtAppName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAppName);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (AppInfo) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkUninstall);
        chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //Init chkbox
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkUninstall);

                if (cb.isChecked())
                {
                    bool.set(position, true); //Gets whether the checkbox is checked
                }
                else if (!cb.isChecked())
                {
                    bool.set(position, false); //Gets whether the checkbox is checked
                }
            }
        });

        //All the position values MUST be set before returning the row
        chk.setChecked(bool.get(position));

        if(item != null)
        {
            //Set data to the different views
            holder.txtAppName.setText(item.appName);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class AppInfo
    {
        TextView txtAppName;
    }

    public class CheckedValues
    {
        public ArrayList<Boolean> checkedValues() { return bool; }
    }
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Context context;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = MainActivity.this;

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.appListView);
        lv.setDivider(null);
        ListAdapter la = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        lv.setAdapter(la);

        //Floating Action Button for uninstalling applications
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        //Disappear the button until the user makes a selection.
        fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

So when a user selects a checkbox I want the fab button to be visible and when they uncheck it, to be invisible.

What I did at first was create a public method in main activity. Set fab to static and the method itself to static then call it from the adapter class passing it a value. MainActivity.isFabVisible(Boolean value).

However, after reading this is not the recommended way of doing this. Therefore,  I tried with interfaces and broadcast receivers but had no luck implementing them properly.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Use a click Listener to listen to the click happening in list from mainActivity. create a public method in your adapter Class which should return a value setting true/false according to checkbox click. So whenever you click something , the listener will give you position, use your adapter object to access the public method and decide whether to show or hide fab. no need to use interface or broadcastreciever for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may Try this :

set this on your Adapter `checkedchangeListener` to check whether its checked or not.Set **true** and **false** respective to **Checked** or **unchecked**

```
if(mContext instanceof MainActivity){
                ((MainActivity)mContext).setMyVisibility(true);
            }
```

In your class:

```
public void setMyVisibility(Boolean value);
{
   if(value)
   {
     fabButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
  else
  {
     fabButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```